# QtJambi - Unicode QLineEdit?

Tags: java, unicode, subscript, qt-jambi, qlineedit

Is it possible to set `QLineEdits` in `QtJambi` to show unicode text?

I need to display unicode subscript characters in a `QLineEdit`, though just setting the text of the `QLineEdit` results in aesthetic error ( A strange line character; `|` ).
I've read that this can be achieved by setting encoding parameters of a `QString`, but now I'm having trouble even creating a new string from my Java inbuilt equivalent.
I can't seem to even make any `QString`.

Has anybody any experience on the matter?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe an alternative support forum is better to handle this matter for you.  Both a mailing list http://lists.qt.nokia.com/mailman/listinfo/qt-jambi-interest and IRC freenode.net channel #qtjambi could establish a lot more facts, ideally produce a 2 page demonstration program then I'm sure a dev can provide some explaination.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've appealed to the mailing list.